# How to read a file passed through stdin in C

Tags: c, stdin

I want to pass a text file to a C program like this `./program < text.txt`. I found out on SO that arguments passed like that dont appear in `argv[]` but rather in `stdin`. How can I open the file in stdin and read it?

Comment: @LiranFunaro - they asked for C - your link is about C++.  C doesn't do `cin` and `cout`.  For C, try reading something like this tutorial (I don't know how good it is - but surely you can Google some others on how to use `stdin` if it isn't what you need).  https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/file-io/intro/

Comment: You have already open this file, `#inlude <stdio.h>` and `fread(buff, size, 1, stdin);`

Comment: You don't open anything (your shell that does the input redirection did that), you just read from `stdin` the usual ways - `fgets()`, `getchar()`, `scanf()`, whatever.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I read a string entered by the user in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023895/how-do-i-read-a-string-entered-by-the-user-in-c)

Comment: The file is not "passed through stdin".  The file *is* stdin.

Comment: It seems I did not understand concept of stdin. I thought I had to pass it to some function. I got it working now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly read the data without having to open the file. `stdin` is already open. Without special checks your program doesn't know if it is a file or input from a terminal or from a pipe.

You can access `stdin` by its file descriptor `0` using `read` or use functions from `stdio.h`. If the function requires a `FILE *` you can use the global `stdin`.

**Example:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define BUFFERSIZE (100) /* choose whatever size is necessary */

/* This code snippet should be in a function */

char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];

if( fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != NULL )
{
    /* check and process data */
}
else
{
    /* handle EOF or error */
}
```

You could also use `scanf` to read and convert the input data. This function always reads from `stdin` (in contrast to `fscanf`).